# Error: import tensorflow.keras.backend as K could not be resolved Pylance(reportMissingImports)

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I'm using tensorflow 1.15.0 in docker container and have issue in importing keras sub-modules.

```
from tensorflow import keras  
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K  
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam, SGD
```

Both backend and Adam, SGD cannot be imported.

Any solutions for this ?

Comment: I could successfully imported above libraries on Colab with Tensorflow 1.15.0. Can you share the full error traceback and exact docker container. Thanks!

Comment: you should install tensorflow-gpu if you are getting Endpoints Error this would solve the issue pip install tensorflow-gpu

Answer (score 0):

I know that is too late, but I confronted the same issue and I just wanted to share the solution that worked successfully for me
try to use this instead :

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from keras import backend as k
```

at least you can use Adam() like this :

```
tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
```

the same goes for SGD() :

```
tf.keras.optimizers.SGD()
```